# Throughput value not as per expected

Tags: jmeter

I am testing 2 website and I have done the same with 3 cases. First case with 3 users, then with 10 and 15. when I observed the throughput is increasing. But my doubt is that I must get the maximum throughput for the first case with3 users, right? I am not getting the result as this. I used ramp up 0 for all cases. Can you guys tell why I didn't get the maximum throughput for the first case?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong, in **ideal** world it should be like this:

- 3 users - you get X throughput (i.e. 10 requests per second)
- 10 users - you should get X * 3 throughput  (i.e. 30 requests per second)
- 15 users - you should get X * 5 thourhgput (i.e. 50 requests per second)

Higher number of concurrent users -> higher throughput, response time should be the same for all scenarios.

It means that your application scales well and performs fast enough no matter if there are 3 or 15 concurrent users.

---

In reality the numbers might be different and you can reach the point when you are increasing the number of concurrent users and throughput remains the same as response time increases. This is called [bottleneck](http://www.performancetestingfun.com/bottlenecks/) and finding these bottlenecks and identifying the root cause is the main idea of the [performance testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing).

So you should gradually increase the load and at the same time observe [throughput and response time metrics](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html). When throughput stops increasing and response time starts increasing - you have the bottleneck, you will need to investigate the reason and report the defect.

Also don't forget about other testing types like [Soak Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) or [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing), these techniques allow to find [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and determine the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html), see [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply, but I wasn't yet able to catch the root cause. Could you please ellaborate?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem in your application. First of all check resources consumption on application under test side, you can do it for example using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) - may be it is simply lack of RAM or overloaded CPU. If not - re-run your test with [profiling tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to check the most resource and time consuming methods, it may be not efficient enough algorithm or slow DB query.

Answer (score 0):

With less number of users we cannot reach maximum tps, throughput increases with increase in user load and for reaching a certain number of users throughput started to decreases. Don't consider that if users are less number we get maximum throughput. Thanks